# Object extending an array

Tags: c#

Does C# got an way of using objects as normal arrays? Like PHP does (ArrayObject)?

Comment: Can you give a PHP example of what you mean? I'm struggling to think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be able to write:

```
string x = foo[0];
```

or

```
Guid y = bar["hello"];
```

then you need to implement an [*indexer*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) in your type. For example, `List<T>` (and indeed any `IList` implementation) has an indexer for accessing items in the collection by index. `Dictionary<T>` (and likewise any `IDictionary`) has an indexer for accessing items by key.